# QString instead of printf

Tags: qt4

How can I show part of a string by QString

```
plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString(a.c_str()))
```

in QtSDK? for example. In C we do it like that:

```
int length = 5;
printf("%*.*s", length, length, "hello there");
```

Comment: `QString(a.c_str())` -- There's also a direct `QString(std::string)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a substring from *QString*. To do that you can use *left*, *right* or *mid* [methods](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) of *QString*.

Here is example from given link:

```
QString x = "Nine pineapples";
QString y = x.mid(5, 4);            // y == "pine"
QString z = x.mid(5);               // z == "pineapples"
```

Comment: the answer is given in QString documentation,but i want to give thanks to @besworland for sharing it here.my answer is half done here.i want to know something else also.....here they are....std::stringstream ss1;
uint32 stamp_1;
ss1<stamp_1;
QString a=ss1.str();
i am not understanding what is the wrong in my code?
i am getting this kind of error:
conversion from ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ to non-scalar type ‘QString’ requested

Answer (score 0):

step1:
QString QString::mid ( int position, int n = -1 ) const
Returns a string that contains n characters of this string, starting at the specified position index.

Returns a null string if the position index exceeds the length of the string. If there are less than n characters available in the string starting at the given position, or if n is -1 (default), the function returns all characters that are available from the specified position.

Example:

```
 QString x = "Nine pineapples";
 QString y = x.mid(5, 4);            // y == "pine"
 QString z = x.mid(5);               // z == "pineapples"
```

step2:
QString QString::fromStdString ( const std::string & str )   [static]
Returns a copy of the str string. The given string is converted to Unicode using the fromAscii() function.

This constructor is only available if Qt is configured with STL compatibility enabled.